# How to iterate down a column of names to populate a new column with the number of occurrences of each name

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a column of a dataframe called "companies" (you can see what it looks like below). I would like to use this column to create another column called "occurrences". My goal is to populate the occurrences column sequentially based on how many times a company name occurs. I want it to look like this

```
company   |   occurrences

company 1 |   1
company 1 |   2
company 1 |   3
company 2 |   1
company 2 |   2
company 3 |   1
company 4 |   1
company 4 |   2
company 5 |   1
company 5 |   2
company 5 |   3
company 5 |   4
```

Unfortunately, I'm having quite a bit of trouble doing this. This is my attempt at starting this but first, it's creating an infinite while loop that I can't figure out how to break out of, and second, even if it worked, this would fill the values incorrectly. Along with that, the if statement nested within the while statement is returning the entire column instead of the final count of companies.

```
 def occurrences(companies):
 occurrences = []
     for i in range(len(companies)):
         x = 0
         occurrences.append(x)
         while str(companies[i]) == str(companies[i+1]):
             x = x+1
             occurrences.append(x)
             if str(companies[i]) is not str(companies[i+1]):
                 x = companies.str.count(companies[i])
                 occurrences.append(x)
     return round_number

 occurrences(companies)
```

I know the line "for i in range(len(companies))" iterates down the column and I know that "str(companies[i]) == str(companies[i+1])" does compare the company names correctly. I believe everything else is completely wrong though. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The best to work with a pandas `DataFrame` is using the (vectorized) functions it provides, take a look at functions `groupby` and also `cumcount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use a loop for it. You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['ocurrence']=df.groupby('company').cumcount()+1
print(df)
```

---

```
      company  ocurrence
0   company 1          1
1   company 1          2
2   company 1          3
3   company 2          1
4   company 2          2
5   company 3          1
6   company 4          1
7   company 4          2
8   company 5          1
9   company 5          2
10  company 5          3
11  company 5          4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a just a few errors:

```
 for i in range(len(companies)):
```

This should be your only loop; it will drive your travel down the column.  Everything else will simply use the `i` line index.

```
     while str(companies[i]) == str(companies[i+1]):
```

Use `if`; you make this check only once per iteration.  Making it a `while` means that something within this `whiel` loop has to alter the value of `i`, or the values in your table -- otherwise, the condition never changes, and you have an infinite loop.

```
         if str(companies[i]) is not str(companies[i+1]):
```

I don't understand why this exists.  First, `is not` *must* be true, as the two objects cannot possibly have the same referent: they're different locations in the same sequence.  If you're trying to do something when the labels are different, then un-indent this and replace it with a simple `else`, referring to the `if` you just made from the ill-formed `while`.